# expected value of the product of two Bernoulli variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

I'm stuck on proving that the product of two Bernoulli variables has expected value equal to the difference between the probability that the variables are the same and the probability that the variables are different.

$$E(XY)= P(X=Y) - P(X \neq Y)$$

Comment: This is false for the usual definition of Bernoulli random variables (taking values $0$ and $1$). I imagine it was intended for the case where $X$ and $Y$ take values $-1$ and $1$. Then $XY=1$ when $X=Y$, and $XY=-1$ when $X\ne Y$.

Answer (score 1):

This statement isn't true. Consider the example where X and Y are independent Bernoulli variables with parameter $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

$$\mathbb{E}[XY] = P(X=1,Y=1) = \frac{1}{4}$$

On the other hand, $$P(X=Y) - P(X\neq Y) = P(X=0,Y=0) + P(X=1,Y=1) - P(X=0,Y=1) - P(X=1,Y=0) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} = 0$$